# CentOS 7 login shell

Tags: bash, centos7

I have 2 host VM's, both have the same application account created, and both have the exact same `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files in `$HOME`, with the same permissions.

Both machines have a `crontab` entry to run a job, but only one of the machines is sourcing the `.bash*` files while the other is not. I have no idea what the difference is which is causing them to behave differently.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have both on the same errata level (latest)?

Comment: Both VM's were built using the same ISO and updated at the same time. They "should" be identical in that regard. However, the account setup was done after the VM's were deployed. However, I cannot detect any difference in the configuration which would account for the difference in the shell startup.

Comment: People write amazing and multiple option to set env variable in cron please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use

Answer (score 0):

Since [there is a sequence of scripts which are sourced upon login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login) you may have a look into [How to set environment variable for everyone under my linux system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system) and [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables), maybe starting with scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`.